# Como fazer box aparecer quando estiver logado

Tags: php, mysql

Bom, eu criei um sistema com `$_SESSION`, e gostaria de saber como eu poderia fazer por exemplo. Tem o login, a pessoa se loga na index, e retorna na mesma página logado, e queria que algumas coisas novas aparecessem para ele, como poderia fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer uma verificação em algum campo da $_SESSION com isset. E após isso exibir.

Exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
  <form method="post" action="">
    ...
  </form>

  <?php if ( isset($_SESSION) ){ ?>

  <div>Só será exibido se entrar no if.</div>

  <?php } ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Documentação: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.isset.php

Comment: Minha função não ficou compatível com esse seu comendo, será que poderia fazer uma pra mim? Por gentileza.

Answer (score 0):

Explicando: Eu dividi minha pagina em pequenos arquivos php (com elementos HTML puro) e verifico se o usuário esta logado se sim a página será composta com um botão logout caso não com botões login e cadastro.

```
session_start();
    if((!isset($_SESSION['email']) == true) and (!isset($_SESSION['pass']) == true)){
            require_once 'components/modals/login-modal.php';
            require_once 'components/modals/create-account-modal.php';
        }else{
            require_once 'components/modals/logout-modal.php';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Depois de logar, pode gravar um dado no `$_SESSION`. Depois, pode verificar se esse valor existe utilizando um `if()` e `isset()`, como sugerido por @Allex.

```php
function logar() {
  $_SESSION['logado'] = true;
}

/* ... depois ... */

<?php
  if ( isset($_SESSION['logado']) && $_SESSION['logado'] )
  {
    echo "<b>Coisas especiais.</b>";
  } else {
    echo "<i>Nada especial.</i>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Da para puxar a informação de quem está online com essa function?